# Web application running on WAS does not call external endpoint

Tags: rest, web-applications, websphere

I have a legacy web application running on Websphere App Server 8.5. My assignment is to call an external Rest API, but it throws an

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I built another brand new application using Quarkus, and it calls the same external API fine. Both applications Quarkus and Web Legacy run on the same machine, same network.
The code of the legacy application goes below:

```
public ResponseEntity<Challenge> init(){
    try {
       System.out.println("###LivenessService.init() - API Test - DEV Server");
       
        URL url = new URL(urlInit);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty(Key", "ab58ebddf2b7dc");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        System.out.println("###LivenessService.init() - chamada efetuada com sucesso");
        System.out.println("### - "+con.getResponseCode());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to provide full stack trace. This just says "connection reset" but you need to find out why. Probably using plain http for https endpoint, or other way around.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for replying. I worked around by skipping SSL validation.